# ArrayList Members of Singleton Being Emptied When Activites Are Destroyed

Tags: android, android-activity, memory-management, singleton, android-lifecycle

I have a singleton that keeps the categories and channels of my music app. I used a singleton because the categories and channels were being loaded from a local JSON file embedded in the app. However, the business needs changed and I am now loading them from a remote JSON file on the server.

Here's the ChannelLab class (roughly):

```
private ArrayList<Channel> mChannels;
private ArrayList<Category> mCategories;

// To be removed later...
private ArrayList<ChannelOld> mChannelsOld;
private static final int CHANNELS_OLD_JSON = R.raw.channels;
//

private static ChannelLab sChannelLab;
private Context mAppContext;

...


public ChannelLab(Context appContext) {
    sChannelLab = this;

    mAppContext = appContext;
    mChannels = new ArrayList<Channel>();
    mCategories = new ArrayList<Category>();

    //
    // To be removed later
    mChannelsOld = new ArrayList<ChannelOld>();
    //
    //
}

public static ChannelLab get(Context c) {
    if (sChannelLab == null) {
        //Crashlytics.log(1, TAG, "sChannelLab NULL");

        sChannelLab = new ChannelLab(c.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sChannelLab;
}

public void loadAll() {
    try {
        //mChannels = loadChannels();
        new LoadChannelsFromServer().execute();

        //
        // To be removed later
        mChannelsOld = loadChannelsOld();
        //
        //
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mChannels = new ArrayList<Channel>();
        Log.e(TAG, "Error loading channels: ", e);
    }

    try {
        //mCategories = loadCategories();
        new LoadCategoriesFromServer().execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mCategories = new ArrayList<Category>();
        Log.e(TAG, "Error loading categories: ", e);
    }
}
```

At the launch, I run the following code to load the categories and the channels:

```
clab = new ChannelLab(getApplicationContext());
clab.setCallback(this);
clab.loadAll();
```

and mCategories and mChannels are filled with the categories and channels.

The problem is that sometimes (most probably when the acitivites are destroyed), the ChannelLab instance is still available, and the mChannels and mCategories are, too, but they are empty. They are not null, but they have 0 size, and that causes null pointer exceptions when resuming actvity and accessing the ChannelLab using:

```
ChannelLab(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
```

What changes do I need to make to be sure that the mCategories and mChannels are still filled with data when there are no activities? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Maybe you should try saving these arrays in SharedPreferences

Comment: if you're using a singleton why are you explicitly calling `clab = new ChannelLab(getApplicationContext());` should it not be `clab = ChannelLab.get(getApplicationContext());`. and in the `get` static method change `c.getApplicationContext()` to just `c`. At the moment each time the Activity is destroyed and recreated it creates a new ChannelLab object which creates empty Arraylists.

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your help, it worked. I was doing something similar before, but without success. Your help was really helpful!